# jetty embedded app using jruby

Tags: jetty, jruby

I'm trying to create my first Jetty embedded mode application following a tutorial on the Eclipse wiki.  I want to do this in JRuby rather than Java.

Here's the Java code:

```
public class ManyConnectors
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Server server = new Server();

    SelectChannelConnector connector0 = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector0.setPort(8080);
    connector0.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
    connector0.setRequestHeaderSize(8192);

    SelectChannelConnector connector1 = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector1.setHost("127.0.0.1");
    connector1.setPort(8888);
    connector1.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(20));
    connector1.setName("admin");

    SslSelectChannelConnector ssl_connector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
    String jetty_home = 
      System.getProperty("jetty.home","../jetty-distribution/target/distribution");
    System.setProperty("jetty.home",jetty_home);
    ssl_connector.setPort(8443);
    SslContextFactory cf = ssl_connector.getSslContextFactory();
    cf.setKeyStore(jetty_home + "/etc/keystore");
    cf.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");
    cf.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g");

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{ connector0, connector1, ssl_connector });

    server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
}
```

I'm having a problem translating this line into the equivalent JRuby:

```
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{ connector0, connector1, ssl_connector });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem? Show your efforts, your trials, your errors.

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a plain old array:

```
server.set_connectors([connector0, connector1, ssl_connector ])
```

EDIT - here's a working example:

```
require 'pp'
require 'java'
require 'jetty-6.1.3.jar'  # in local dir
require 'jetty-util-6.1.3.jar' # in local dir
require 'servlet-api-2.5-6.1.3.jar' # in local dir

class MyHandler
  include org.mortbay.jetty.Handler
  def destroy;end
  def start;end
  def getServer;end
  def handle(target, request, response, dispatch)
    pp target
    pp request
  end
  def setServer(server);end
end
server = Java::OrgMortbayJetty::Server.new


connector0 = org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.new
connector0.set_port(8080)
connector0.set_max_idle_time(30000)
# connector0.set_request_header_size(8192)  # could not find this method

server.set_connectors([connector0])
server.set_handlers([MyHandler.new])
server.start
server.join
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  You are a scholar and a gentleman.